# istio egress tracing / metrics for a mitm https connection

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I want to get egress traces and metrics from a pod which I don't control much (in terms of code) to a third-party egress endpoint (that I don't control at all). You can think of it as e.g. traffic from a wordpress installation to `api.wordpress.org`.

I plan to terminate the tls on the egress and then create a new tls session from there. For that I generate a certificate for `api.wordpress.org` from a CA that I can inject into the pod.

I have the following configuration:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: egress-api-wordpress-org
spec:
  hosts:
    - api.wordpress.org
  gateways:
    - mesh
    - egress-api-wordpress-org
  tls:
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 443
          sniHosts:
            - api.wordpress.org
      route:
        - destination:
            host: istio-egressgateway.istio-egress.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 443
  http:
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - egress-api-wordpress-org
          port: 443
      route:
        - destination:
            host: api.wordpress.org
            port:
              number: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: egress-api-wordpress-org
spec:
  hosts:
    - api.wordpress.org
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
spec:
  host: api.wordpress.org
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 443
        tls:
          mode: SIMPLE
```

With this setup I see the traffic passing through the egress (and I have the metrics and traces egress-side). However, there are no details on the origin -- which kind of makes sense as the sidecar's envoy can't see what's the traffic inside.

Is there any way to provide the origin details to the egress without hacking on the origin pod's source code? I'm generally fine with weird things like tls-in-tls if it's possible to set it up (I'm not sure I can terminate tls on egress twice -- for istio_mutual and simple layers).

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is k3s v1.21.1+k3s1 with istio 1.12.1. I'm curios though, how is k8s version relevant to the question? It's more of "how do I set up envoy to do what I want", I'm not sure that k8s version would have affected anything in this setup.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you cannot see origins when checking traffic flow in your distributed tracing system. To correctly correlate spans into a single trace (a complete view of the traffic flow), your applications need to propagate the appropriate HTTP headers. More information can be found in the [Trace context propagation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation) documentation. If this does not dispel your doubts, please carefully describe / draw up the traffic flow you have at your place.

Comment: You can't do that out of the box, yes, but technically the sidecar envoy can incapsulate the tls payload in its own mtls connection to send the traffic to the egress. I'm just not sure if/how to do that in istio setup specifically